# Как найти количество потоков используемых процессором?

Tags: c#

Как найти количество потоков используемых процессором? И текущую скорость работы процессора (GHz)?
Вот картинка - 
[image: что нужно]

Как можно вытащить эти данные?

Comment: CreateToolhelp32Snapshot

Answer (score 0):

Я вот не уверен, скорость какого ядра показывает `Task Manager`, и что выдаст этот код:

```
int threadsCount = Process.GetProcesses()
    .Select(p => p.Threads.Count)
    .Sum();

uint clock;
using (var mo = new ManagementObject("Win32_Processor.DeviceID='CPU0'"))
{
    clock = (uint)mo["CurrentClockSpeed"];
}

Console.WriteLine(clock);
Console.WriteLine(threadsCount);
```